# How do I combine a heatmap with a curve in a panel

Tags: python, panel, heatmap, curve, holoviews

I tried this code :

```
import holoviews as hv
import panel as pn
hv.extension('bokeh')

gspec = pn.GridSpec(width=800, height=600)
gspec[1, 0] = hv.HeatMap([(0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 10), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 3)])
gspec[2, 0] = hv.Curve([1, 2, 3])
gspec.show()
```

But I got following error message:

> <bokeh.server.server.Server at 0x199dc103fc8>
> ERROR:bokeh.core.validation.check:E-1009 (INCOMPATIBLE_SCALE_AND_RANGE): A Scale is incompatible with one or more ranges on the same plot dimension: incompatibility on x-dimension: FactorRange(id='1076', ...)/LinearScale(id='1133', ...), incompatibility on y-dimension: FactorRange(id='1077', ...)/LinearScale(id='1135', ...) [Figure(id='1128', ...)]

What am I doing wrong or how can I combine a heatmap with a curve?

Comment: This works just fine for me. What version of HoloViews do you have?

Comment: I am using holoviews version 1.12.7-py_0 and panel version 0.6.4-py_0

Comment: Me either, I can repplicate your example. Only modification could be:

`heatmap = hv.HeatMap([(0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 10), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 3)])
heatmap = heatmap.aggregate(function=np.mean)
gspec[1, 0] = heatmap` (holoviews==1.13.2)